# Any solution to make Browser Link work with ASP.NET Core RC2 project while using gulp?

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2, browser-link

I use **Visual Studio 2015 Community** with **ASP.NET Core RC2**. I have all the required tools installed and everything is working fine with one exception.
When I create a new **ASP.NET Core Web Application** or load a saved ASP.NET Core Web Application the **View in Browser** functionality of **Browser Link loads a wrong address in the Web Browser**.
**If I type the correct address in the browser**, the Browser Link Dashboard is updated and the application **is listed as Unknown**.

After a lot of reverse engineering and tinkering i found that the problem is linked  to the **Node.js** module **gulp** in the **node_modules** folder of the project.
 
If I **delete** the **gulp** folder before loading the project **Browser Link works just fine**. It is still working after the **gulp** module is downloaded by the IDE back in the **node_modules** folder. If I reload the solution without deleting **gulp**, **Browser Link doesn't work anymore**.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: The best solution for me was to go back to .NET 4.5.X Too many errors, too many bugs, bad documentation, etc. in RC1, RC2, etc.

Comment: For me the advantages of ASP.NET Core outweigh the disadvantages

Comment: Yes... I suppose...  We have been found errors (criticals) with Kestrel making down our app.